# Activecampaign - Adding checkbox values via API

Tags: php, api, checkbox

I am trying to submit multiple values into an AC field using the contact_sync PHP API.

The field has been set as a checkbox field and I can select multiple items in AC itself but I am not sure how to submit multiple items via the API.

```
'field[17]'                => 'Option 1, Option 2',
```

I thought this would work as it does work for multiple lists. Does it need to be an array of sometype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can submit multiple values to a single checkbox field via the API with double pipes (||), like this:

field[76,0]=option1||option2||option3